# Freeze at the end of Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb, freeze

I have a problem with my Ubuntu installation.
I made an Ubuntu 18.04 bootable USB, but when I install on my laptop at the end of the installation when the message "Please restart your computer..." appear. I click on restart and at this moment the messeage disappear and my laptop freeze.
It did nothing and I can't do anything else.

I have Windows 10 on my SSD and I try to install Ubuntu on my HD.

My laptop :
MSI GS63 7RD Stealth / Intel Core i7-7700HQ - 8Gb RAM - 128Gb SSD - 1 Tb HD

Comment: Yes my laptop always boot form cold start.

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest is, before installing the OS in disk, use the option try with out installing and check whether the OS package works with out any issues. Try installing the OS with default settings rather than trying to create swap and other OS partitions manually. Also make sure the HDD partition is having minimum storage available for the installation.

Comment: I did this and i format all my discs with gparted. I try to reinstall my OS (W10 & Ubuntu)to see if it's work